# Python Indexing Issue results in KeyError: 0

Tags: python, list, dictionary

NOTE: SEM1period1 contains list ["a", "b", "c", "d"] just like the elective list, except it is being passed as an arugment into this function.

The break appears to happen in the while loop at the first For statement. The program returns KeyError: 0

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

elecStorage = []

elective = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
prereq = []

dict1 = {
1: SEM1period1, 2: SEM1period2,
3: SEM1period3, 4: SEM1period3,
4: SEM1period5, 6: SEM1period6,
7: SEM1period7, 8: SEM1period8
}

period1 = []
period2 = []
period3 = []
period4 = []
period5 = []
period6 = []
period7 = []
period8 = []

periodDict = { 
1: period1, 2: period2,
3: period3, 4: period4,
5: period5, 6: period6,
7: period7, 8: period8
}

someNumber = 0

while someNumber <= 7:
    for index in dict1[someNumber]: #Looks through the first through eigth SEM1Period(1-8)
        for index2 in periodDict[someNumber]: #Looks through the first through eight periods to append to.
            if len(index) < 1:
                index2.append("Free Period")
                break
            elif period in index2:
                break
            elif period in prereq:
                elecStorage.append(index)
            else:
                print "Lololol"
        break           
    someNumber = someNumber + 1
```

What the code should be doing is for each list in dict1(someNumber) checking in each list in periodDict(someNumbe)r as well (so the first list in dict1 corresponds to the first list in periodDict, and all the way up through all 8) until the if/then statements are satisfied.

I might be going about this all wrong as my programming career isn't very extensive and I'm not very good yet, so take it easy on me please.

If you need further clarification, post a comment.

Thanks in advance, friends.

Comment: A bit of advice: any time you find yourself trying to use `variable#`, instead use a list. If `period1 = []` then `period = [None, [] ]` so that `period[1]` is the new `period1`. Use zero-indexing if you can, so you can avoid that ugly `[None, ...]`

Comment: It looks to me like a complete code re-factor would serve you better than duct taping this code back together. Can you tell us the **problem** you're trying to solve with this code, rather than the way this code should solve that problem?

Comment: I have to agree with Adam here, but if you want to take the cheap way out: `someNumber = 0` -> `someNumber = 1` and as Adam also said: `dict1(someNumber)` -> `dict1[someNumber]`

Comment: Another bit about sequences: you're not ACTUALLY using any dictionaries here, you're using lists that you've saved as a dictionary. If you're only using numbers as keys, just use a list! :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought when I was referencing the keys inside of the dictionary I had to start with 0, turns out I start with 1???

Comment: Of course I do, I'm an idiot. I SET it to 1!!!